# SQL Server CE 4.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am looking into using SQL Server Ce 4.0 for my personal blog application along with ASP.NET MVC MVC3 and Entity framework CTP 5.

My question is does SQL Server CE 4 have full LINQ support, i.e. all operators and the like ? Does anyone know of any article/study done to test the functionality of SQL Server CE LINQ functionality?

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ features are broadly provided by the SQL client you're using, not the database, and it's up to the client to map the LINQ operations into SQL etc. that the database will understand. It's usually only very simple SQL.

The ['introducing SQL Server CE 4' blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2010/07/07/introducing-sql-server-compact-4-0-the-next-gen-embedded-database-from-microsoft.aspx) says it supports the Entity Framework, so if you're using the Entity Framework then you should have access to all the usual EF-based LINQ operations.

Are there any in particular you're worried you're not going to get?